# Remote debugging with informations?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, remote-debugging

I'm using the Visual Studio 2012 Remote debugguer and it works fine.
But I'm not getting a lot of informations.

I agree with the fact that I can't have the source code when an unhandled exception is throw but I'm surprised that the remote debugguer don't send me the line or the function or simply the stacktrace.

All I got is, for example :

Unhandled ArgumentNullException in System.core.dll

Is there a way to compile a program (with VS 2012) that can send more information in remote debugging?

Comment: do you have pdb files along with dll/exe on remote machine?

Comment: Yes I got it, can I do something with it ?

Comment: Bear in mind that you can output data to a log (just write the variables you are interested in knowing to a text file) and analyse that, this can be easier than remote debugging in some situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check following points :

1. The assemblies should be built in Debug mode instead of Release mode
2. The debug symbols should be present at target location (PDB files)
3. The source code should not have been modified after the remote assemblies were built.
4. I think you should have administrator privileges for this to complete.

Comment: 1. I've done it
2. It is
3. It has not been edited
4. I do

But I don't get the source code, only a ArgumentNullException in System.Core.DLL

Any idea ?

Comment: Make sure you have turned on Managed code debugging in your remote debugger and not just "Native code debugging". Using managed code debugging requires that you use the same user in Windows/Visual Studio  on your host as well as on the client.

Comment: I saw in VS how to compile on "Managed code debugging" but I can't find it in the remote debugguer (there's not a lot of menus).
But I'm gonna try with the same user.